# Initialize a List<int> with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I am initializing a `List<int>` in a constructor by storing two simple constants, MinValue and MaxValue as such:

```
private const int MinValue = 1;
private const int MaxValue = 100;

private List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

public Class()
{
    for (int i = MinValue ; i < MaxValue ; i++)
    {
        integerList .Add(i);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to just initialize the list with a simple LINQ query?  Since a `List<T>` can be constructed with an `IEnumerable<T>`, does a query of the following form exist?

```
private List<int> integerList = new List<int>(<insert query here>);
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Note that the `MaxValue` is exclusive in your code, i.e. it will produce a list with values from 1 to 99. Is that the intention?

Comment: @Guffa - It actually is but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)

```
List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(MinValue, MaxValue - MinValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`Enumerable.Range(int start, int count)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

> Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.

A simple example, using your `MinValue` and `MaxValue` variables:

```
List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(MinValue, MaxValue - MinValue).ToList();
```

Note that if `MaxValue` is less than `MinValue`, the `count` parameter will be less than zero and an [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MaxValue is always > MinValue,

```
var integerList = Enumerable.Range(MinValue, MaxValue-MinValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a collection initializer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

private List integerList = new List{MinValue, MaxValue};

Comment: Ah, i didn't realize it was inclusive... Yeah, use Enumerable.Range

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Enumerable.Range`

```
List<int> integerList = Enumerable.Range(MinValue, MaxValue - MinValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try IEnumerable.Range(MinValue, MaxValue-MinValue).ToList(): [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx)